# Copy paste the columns used range

Tags: excel, vba

I have wrote a code which is working fine but it copies the whole column rather than used range.

Can someone please help me in this regard. I have tried it using `lastrow` but do not know how to do this and please also share that if i want to add more column then how it would be done.

or is there better way to do this please share.

Your help means a lot to me.

```
lastrow = totalWS.Cells(totalWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Sheet1.Columns(1).Copy
Sheet3.Columns(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheet1.Columns(2).Copy
Sheet3.Columns(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheet1.Columns(4).Copy
Sheet3.Columns(4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheet1.Columns(5).Copy
Sheet3.Columns(5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheet1.Columns(6).Copy
Sheet3.Columns(6).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheet1.Columns(7).Copy
Sheet3.Columns(7).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: The number of rows in a column differs for each Excel version, but recently it has exceeded 1 million rows. This is not a good idea. Copying to fit the size of the data does not waste resources.

Comment: Instead of copying the full row `Sheet1.Columns(1).Copy` just copy the desired range `Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Copy`. Same for pasting. Note that your question is a bit unclear. Can you [edit] your question and be more precise in what you are actually trying to do? Screenshots can help too to explain.

Comment: The code you wrote does what you intended. It copies columns. If you would like to copy `UsedRange`- use it!

Comment: Thank you @Pᴇʜ your suggestion is using lastrow is very good. Let me clear it. I just want to copy the Mentioned Columns used range and paste into Sheet3.

Comment: @Mento As Dy.Lee said copying the used range or copying the entire column is the same effort for Excel. It does not waste resources. So the result is exactly the same. So I see no point in changing anything here.

Comment: Thank you  @Dy.Lee and @@Pᴇʜ for making this thing clear.

Comment: I was looking for another way to do this @Maciej Los

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set Ws = Sheets(1)
    Set toWs = Sheets(3)
    
    arr = Array(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7)
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        With Ws
            vDB = .Range(.Cells(1, arr(i)), .Cells(Rows.Count, arr(i)).End(xlUp))
        End With
        toWs.Cells(1, arr(i)).Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer @Dy.Lee there is an issue let me show you Sheet1 data https://ibb.co/d2H3xGn and the code result https://ibb.co/xFDfq7W. The code paste the less result rather than complete

Comment: I think its removing the duplicates @Dy.Lee

Answer (score 0):

Actually since every copy action takes its time, it gets faster the less single copy actions you have. So copy adjacent rows **together** would make it faster:

```
Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Columns(1), Sheet1.Columns(2)).Copy  'copy column 1 to 2
Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Columns(1), Sheet3.Columns(2)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Columns(4), Sheet1.Columns(7)).Copy  'copy column 4 to 7
Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Columns(4), Sheet3.Columns(7)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Now instead of 6 copy actions you only have 2 copy actions, even if the same amount of data is copied this should be measurable faster than copying column by column (even if you copy in a loop, this should be faster).

Comment: Thank you @Pᴇʜ
 for the great idea.